# How to access SQL Server from docker container?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, docker, iis, docker-for-windows

I am working now with the MVC5 application over .net framework 4.6.1 and I'm using windows containers. One of the requirements is to create docker image for application. I successfully pulled [microsoft/aspnet:4.6.2](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/aspnet/) image and deployed a web application in the container. In *Dockerfile* I have added "EXPOSE 1433", to be sure that SQL Server can access host through this port. 
The problem is with SQL connection. Established connection leads to following error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'
```

I should mention that connection string is with enabled **Integration Security**. I have tried to set the application pool identity:

```
Set-ItemProperty IIS:\AppPools\DefaultAppPool\ -Name processModel -Value @{username='domain\user';password='somepassword';identityType=3 }
```

This, unfortunately, leads to "*HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable*", because of the stopped application pool.
I have checked the windows event store where I have found three events:

> Application pool DefaultAppPool has been disabled. Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) encountered a failure when it started a worker process to serve the application pool.
>
> Application pool DefaultAppPool has been disabled. Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) did not create a worker process to serve the application pool because the application pool identity is invalid.
>
> The identity of application pool DefaultAppPool is invalid. The user
>   name or password that is specified for the identity may be incorrect,
>   or the user may not have batch logon rights. If the identity is not
>   corrected, the application pool will be disabled when the application
>   pool receives its first request.  If batch logon rights are causing
>   the problem, the identity in the IIS configuration store must be
>   changed after rights have been granted before Windows Process
>   Activation Service (WAS) can retry the logon. If the identity remains
>   invalid after the first request for the application pool is processed,
>   the application pool will be disabled. The data field contains the
>   error number

I have checked credentials, they are correct. My thoughts are that container has own private domain. That's why I can't connect to SqlServer.
Researching I've found [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/manage-serviceaccounts).

Have anyone tried to configure the Active Directory in docker container? How do you solve the problem with SQL connection?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use GMSA account if you want to use integrated Windows Authentication inside container. Google it or look at my blog here (https://github.com/artisticcheese/artisticcheesecontainer/wiki)